# Terminate (possibly) multibyte string?

Tags: c, substring, multibyte, null-terminated

I am working on a C code and struggling to find a way to terminate a string after specific number of characters. For example I need to terminate string `data` after 3 characters. If it's a plain ASCII string, I can do something like

```
data[3] = 0;
```

But in my case any of the characters could be multibyte like È or À. What would be the best way to terminate such string after given number of *characters*?

UPDATE:

Basically:

```
char s_mon[7];

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
strftime(s_mon, 7, "%b", tick_time);
```

Current locale is French. Month is being stored as "févr.". Need it to be "fév", but this need to be universal so entries like "mars" could also be cut to 3 chars.

Comment: What is the declaration for `data`

Comment: Depending on the encoding (you should know what encoding you are using), there are precise rules for using multi-byte sequences. You analyze the string from left to right, considering those rules, until you get past the Nth character. Then you can put a zero (for UTF-8, a single 0 is ok for example).

Comment: `È`, `À` do not _require_ "multibyte".  With [8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) they are simply codes 200 and 192.   What is the character set you are using?  How did code read the text in the first place?

Comment: Updated the post with example.

Comment: strftime returns the number of characters.

Comment: @stark I thought it returned number of bytes?

Comment: In any case, if the number it returns is not 0, then it has already put a null terminator on your string.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up reusing this [utf_str_to_upper](https://github.com/jrmobley/pebble-utf8/blob/master/src/c/pebble-utf8.c#L50) function. The function correctly deals with multibyte values. It also converts string to uppercase (which I also needed) but that functionality can be stripped if needed.

The only modification I did is pass second parameter `limit` which is limit in *characters* at which I need to cut the string. The function then inserts terminator at correct byte position and returns the byte position. Here's complete code:

```
uint8_t utf8_str_to_upper(char* s, uint8_t limit) {

    uint8_t char_no = 0;
    uint8_t* p;

    for (p = (uint8_t*)s; *p; ++p) {

        // (<128) ascii character
        // U+00000000 – U+0000007F: 0xxxxxxx
        if (*p < 0b10000000) {
            if (*p >= 0x61 && *p <= 0x7A) {
                *p = *p - 0x20; // a~z -> A~Z
            }

        // (<192) unexpected continuation byte
        } else if (*p < 0b11000000) {

        // (<224) 2 byte sequence
        // U+00000080 – U+000007FF: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
        } else if (*p < 0b11100000) {
            uint16_t code = ((uint16_t)(p[0] & 0b00011111) << 6) | (p[1] & 0b00111111);
            if (
                (code >= 0x00E0 && code <= 0x00F6) || // à~ö -> À~Ö
                (code >= 0x00F8 && code <= 0x00FE)    // ø~þ -> Ø~Þ
            ) {
                code -= 0x0020;
                p[0] = 0b11000000 | ((code >> 6) & 0b00011111);
                p[1] = 0b10000000 | ( code       & 0b00111111);
            }
            ++p;

        // (<240) 3 byte sequence
        // U+00000800 – U+0000FFFF: 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        } else if (*p < 0b11110000) {
            p += 2;

        // (<248) 4 byte sequence
        // U+00010000 – U+001FFFFF: 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        } else if (*p < 0b11111000) {
            p += 3;

        // (<252) 5 byte sequence
        // U+00200000 – U+03FFFFFF: 111110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        } else if (*p < 0b11111100) {
            p += 4;

        // (<254) 6 byte sequence
        // U+04000000 – U+7FFFFFFF: 1111110x 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        } else if (*p < 0b11111110) {
            p += 5;
        }

        if (limit) {
            char_no++;

            if (char_no == limit) {
               *(p + 1) = 0;
               return p-(uint8_t*)s + 1;
               break;
            }

        }

    }

    return p-(uint8_t*)s + 1;
}
```

Comment: Please note that in Unicode, é can be represented either as a precombined character, or as a base character + diacritic, so you'll first need to normalize the input to an appropriate form, e.g: to NFC to get é as a precomposed character.

Comment: @ninjalj actually in this case (Pebble Dev) I have to decide composed chars into multibyte to be properly displayed. That function I piggy-backed on is a part of the package that deals with this https://github.com/jrmobley/pebble-utf8